# Convert and compare a field datatype in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a Varchar2 field named Contract_Value and its values are as follows,

```
Contract_Value
---------------
USD 300,000
EUR 120,215.65
AUD 237,176.39
JPY 31,284.32
```

Now I need do a validation to this field for a dashboard application as follows,

```
 SELECT COUNT(*), VALUE FROM
 (SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE(A.CONTRACT_VALUE, '[^.0-9]') > 100 
              THEN 'P' ELSE 'F' END AS VALUE FROM DOCUMENTS A) 
 GROUP BY VALUE;
```

But its throwing an error that *INVALID NUMBER* 
The reason is given the CONTRACT_VALUE field is VARCHAR2 as mentioned above and my validation is with Number which is **> 100**

I tried to use **CAST and TO_NUMBER** keywords to change the Data type from VARCHAR2 to NUMBER but still no luck.

Comment: Fix the schema and don't store the value together with the currency in one string. That's more than horrible. Have a `number` column for the value and a `varchar2` for the currency or even better use a foreign key pointing to a currency table.

Comment: For given sample data, it is working fine. You must have corrupt data in your db. Something like two dots or etc.

Comment: What is the value in `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` in your db?